# How to convert letters with accents, umlauts, etc to their ASCII counterparts in Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ascii

I am trying to figure out a way to convert all letters with accents, or umlauts, or whatever it may be, to plain text:

ä, ö, ü, é, etc. to go to a, o, u, e, etc.

How would I do this in Swift 2.0?

The other question that answers this is in Perl, but I need it for Swift and I am stumped on how to do so.

Comment: The referenced thread has solutions for both Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: @MartinR I did not find this. Thank you for bringing to my attention.